# Based from experience, is dreamfactory better paired with a RDBMS like MySQL or NoSQL like MongoDB

Tags: mysql, nosql

This is our first time to create a data logging web application and we have chosen to use Dreamfactory as the backend framework. We have been used to with MySQL from the past with small amount of data but now considering into trying NoSQL like MongoDB.

These are the data that we are trying to log is basically timestamp of devices and when it was detected by a certain sensor and the signal strength when it was detected. So these items will be logged:

1. ClientDeviceID
2. HostDeviceID
3. Timestamp
4. SignalStrength

I'm trying to determine from the two database if which one is efficiently handling this type of data to be logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DreamFactory works just fine with either SQL or NoSQL, and the API will actually be the same to GET or PUT data. The fields you have above make sense for either SQL or NoSQL. The only difference is that you need to create schema for the SQL table you want to use. Here is a tutorial that is very similar to your use case:

http://thenewstack.io/tutorial-prototyping-a-sensor-node-and-iot-gateway-with-arduino-and-raspberry-pi-part-1/

Disclaimer: I work for DreamFactory Software.